# how to perform multi left-edge keyword matching in solr

Tags: solr, solr4

I have a requirement using Solr's schema.xml, where I need to search for a left-edge keyword in a Multiword wherein the search should be performed for each left-edge keyword after the delimiter.
For examples: Lets say my 
1-> Title is :  Split Air Condtioner
2-> Title is : Plastic chair

Now when I try to query on "air". My delimiter is space

I want it to give me only "Split Air Conditioner" and not "Plastic chair"

Note: Plastic chair appear in my result as "air" is contained in ch(air) keyword. I am using EdgeNGramFilterFactory currently.

Comment: Can you share your schema and field definitions?

Answer (score 0):

You should **StandardTokenizerFactory** instead of **EdgeNGramFilterFactory** for title field.

But yes, As John suggested please share your schema and field definition as it will help us to resolve your issue